# WPF Text character 'g', 'q' and others get cut off in a TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TabControl with a custom template. The TabItems also have a custom template:

```
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="10,5,10,5">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Something basic but still. The issue is that if the header contains characters that are a tad longer (like g, q or p), their bottom side gets cropped off:

[image]

Is there a workaround for this? I have tried adding a margin to the content presenter instead of the padding and the result is the same.

Comment: remove the bottom padding `Padding="10,5,10,0"`

Comment: The `VerticalAlignment = "Center"` would make the "GGGggg" go a bit too low than intended. This will work for fixed height stuff (but in this case, fixed height wouldn't even require the padding/margin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the paddling, try to put `0` from bottom and also change `paddling` of control to `0` where this `ControlTemplate` is going to be used.
In your case:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="10,5,10,0">
    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: definitely @Andrei, Its all about your design and requirement.